Finding a $ ( non-numberic) in an array of numbers whose N is not known
Recently I got the above question. Here, $ (a non-numeric) data is to be find out in an array whose N (Length) is not known. One simplest approach is linear search by going one by one and comparing with symbol $ but it requires O(N) and N is not known. Is there any feasible solution to above question
I know Binary Search, but It requires Bounded End points. I searched more and found that Exponential Search that says increasing the Right-bound by factor of 2 of Binary Search until the range got where the Element will surely present. But here $  as a non-numeric character How will we get the range that confirms as $ is incomparable to numbers ?

Binary search is only useful when data is sorted in some way. As you have no such specification the $ could be anywhere in the array, and you would not learn anything more about its position by looking at other elements, so unless there is something you have not told us, there is no other way then to check each value, one after the other, until you are lucky enough to hit that $.

The question makes little sense in more ways than one, but let's set it all aside and restate it in very easy terms. I give you a big box full of cans of tuna. One of the cans contains a gold coin sealed inside. You cannot know if there is a coin without opening the can. How many cans do you need to open to guarantee that you find the coin? First solve this for the case when you know exactly how many cans are there in the box. Then think about what happens when the box is in fact a huge dark warehouse and you have no idea how many cans could possibly be there. A million? A billion? A trillion?

Yes. I agree but this  is the question asked in the interview.

I guess they provided some info that you may have missed.

I guess they expected you to give the simple answer O(N)
